# how to publish products to specific amazon marketpalce

Tags: php, api, e-commerce, amazon-mws

i am a seller and i have 2 marketplaces,

`1) amazon.com`

`2) webstore`

i want to send via mws product feed to my webstore,i have the marketplace id.

this is the code i am using.

```
$parameters =  array ('MarketplaceIdList' => $this->marketPlaceId,
'Merchant' =>  $this->merchantId, 'FeedType' =>
$feedType,'FeedContent' => $feedHandle, 'PurgeAndReplace' =>
false,'ContentMd5' =>
base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true)),);       

$request = new
MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);
```

this is what is written in the amazpn PDF

> Do not confuse the optional MarketplaceIdList parameter with the Marketplace parameter in a request. The
>   Marketplace parameter is no longer used for authentication and is deprecated, but it remains in the request for
>   backward compatibility.

the parameter "MarketplaceIdList" is not working when i use it, it publish to both marketplaces instend of only to one marketplace.

please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array($MARKETPLACE_ID));
$parameters = array(
             'Merchant' => $MERCHANT_ID,
             'MarketplaceIdList' => $marketplaceIdArray,
             'FeedType' => '_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_',
             'FeedContent' => $feedHandle,
             'PurgeAndReplace' => false, //Leave this PurgeAndReplace to false so that it want replace whole product in amazon inventory
             'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true))
         );
```